# Ph of acid would be one?

Tags: organic-chemistry, ph, drugs

I am interested in the chemical lsd or "acid". I wanted to know if lsd is acid in its pure form would that mean it is water?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No! Don't get fooled by the slang term.

LSD is the abbreviation for lysergic acid diethylamide. However, the parent lysergic acid (see structure) is indeed a carboxylic acid.

[image: lysergic acid]